# Postfix as a MTA, and not being able to receive e-mail

Tags: postfix, alpine-mail

I'm using postfix and I get the following log entry:

```
 Transcript of session follows.

 Out: 220 catch22bbs.com ESMTP
 In:  EHLO mail-it0-f43.google.com
 Out: 250-catch22bbs.com
 Out: 250-PIPELINING
 Out: 250-SIZE
 Out: 250-ETRN
 Out: 250-STARTTLS
 Out: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
 Out: 250-8BITMIME
 Out: 250-DSN
 Out: 250 SMTPUTF8
 In:  STARTTLS
 Out: 454 4.7.0 TLS not available due to local problem

 Session aborted, reason: lost connection

 For other details, see the local mail logfile
```

AFAIK, I have TLS installed. I don't understand this error.
I'm using openSuSE Tumbleweed.

Thanks.

Comment: "For other details, see the local mail logfile"

Comment: I should of said, that i'm using gmail's "free e-mail relay", and that I get that log entry from google (my gmail account).

Comment: I'm not sure where that "local mail logfile" is..

Comment: It will be more than likely referring to `var/log/maillog`

Comment: No such file or directory.

Comment: you may need to specify where postfix should log to.